# Can't have a Vue shortcut (by reference) to a reactive variable?

Tags: vue.js, reactive-programming

I have a Pinia store with an object "objData", which holds one or more objects, with some additional metadata, which ends up becoming a fairly long variable. It has to be used in quite a number of places, therefore I made a "shortcut" variable instead to the "data" property. However, this shortcut fails to be reactive, whereas the variable i'm pointing to **is** reactive.

The Pinia object looks like:

```
objData: {
    "fruit": {
        data: {...},
        ...
    },
    "candy": {
        data: {...},
        ...
    },
}
```

The setup-function:

```
setup() {
    const myStore = useMyStore()
    // const fruit = myStore.objData['fruit'].data // <- direct, doesn't work
    // const fruit = reactive(myStore.objData['fruit'].data) // <- reactive, doesn't work
    const fruit = computed(() => myStore.objData['fruit'].data) // works
    return {
        myStore,
        fruit,
    }
}
```

The data change: (I'm sure I don't need to both do reactive() and refs(), or any at all, but I've tried all kinds of things to get reactivity in my shortcut). This happens in a composable that has access to the store.

```
if (!("fruit" in store.objData)) {
    set(myStore.objData, "fruit", reactive({
        data: ref(null),
    }))
}
set(myStore.objData["fruit"], 'data', objNewData)
```

The page:

```
<div>
    {{myStore.objData['fruits'].data.fruit_name}} OK
    {{fruit.fruit_name}} OK, if computed(), otherwise not reactive
</div>
```

Unless I'm using a computed, I only get the inital value, which doesn't get updated when the store updates.

1. Is it actually bad/expensive/wrong to use a computed() to have a reactive data object in the page in this way? It "feels" wrong, but other than that I have no arguments against it.
2. (Why) is it not possible to simply make a variable by reference to a reactive variable, I always thought you're just pointing to a memory address.

I'm struggeling to provide an example, as this thing is so deeply integrated in my app. I'm at this point hoping for a glaring mistake on my part, or a simple answer that explains it.

Note 1: I'm using Vue2 with the composition API add-on.

Note 2: This is a very simplified example.

Comment: have you tried object destructuring?

Comment: A good idea. But it too is not reactive, I assumed this is what you meant: const {objData} = storeToRefs(myStore)
const fruit = objData.value["fruit"].data